# Scala - object extends abstract class and takes parameters

Tags: scala, class, object, apply, derived

> //File Animal.scala

```
abstract class Animal {

    val name: String

    def getSomething(tClass: TypeClass): String = {
        tClass.tName.split('.').lift(0)
    }

    def apply(tClass: TypeClass): SomeOtherClassType = {
        // something... 

    }
```

> // File: *DogSpike*, this is used for some specific cases (overwrites
>   base class val)

```
object DogSpike extends Animal {

  override val name: String = "Spike"
}
```

*this call then works (calls apply)*
 `myTransformation(() => DogSpike(this))`

Now I would like to create a more generic object that one can pass arguments but I am unable to.

It would work to create a derived Object from Animal that takes one arguments and being able to use the apply call

```
object TheDog(name: String) extends Animal {

  override val name: String = "Spike"
//...
}
```

*not sure how to implicitly call Animal.apply for `TheDog` object where I could pass a parameter (name)*
 `myTransformation(() => TheDog(this))`

```
// also this seems to be incorrect "*Wrong top statement declaration*"
object TheDog(val n: String) extends Animal {
   override val name: String = n
//...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As of  `*Wrong top statement declaration*` (I can understand only this part of your question) - you can't have constructor in object as `object` is a singleton, so you should use a case class (ADT):

```
final case class TheDog(name: String) extends Animal

scala>TheDog("Spike")
res2_2: TheDog = TheDog("Spike")
```

`val` and companion object with `apply` is added automatically for case classes, so you don't need to define your own own `apply` in `Animal`. `case class TheDog(val name: String)` is same as `case class TheDog(name: String)`.

I's also use `trait`s instead of abstract class:

```
trait Animal {

    val name: String

    def getSomething: String = {
        "Dog: " + name
    }

}
```

I don't understand your `TypeClass` type, but if you really want type classes:

```
trait Animal {
  def name: String
}

final case class TheDog(name: String) extends Animal
final case class TheCat(name: String) extends Animal

implicit class RichDog(dog: TheDog){
    def getSomething: String = {
        "Dog" + dog.name
    }
}

implicit class RichCat(cat: TheCat){
    def getSomething: String = {
        "Cat: " + cat.name
    }
}

scala> TheDog("Spike").getSomething
res4_5: String = "DogSpike"
scala> TheCat("Tom").getSomething
res4_6: String = "Cat: Tom"
```

---

About calling `apply` "implicitly", I don't know why would anyone need this, but:

```
trait AnimalFactory[A <: Animal] {

   def apply(name: String)(implicit constructor: String => A) = constructor(name)

}

object TheeeDog extends AnimalFactory[TheDog]

implicit def createDog(name: String) = TheDog(name)

TheeeDog("Spike")
```

Of course you have to provide `createDog` and make it visible for a client, but it doesn't really make sense if you can just use ADTs and define additional required `apply`s in companion object:

```
  case class TheMouse(name: String)
  object TheMouse{
    def apply(isJerry: Boolean): TheMouse = if (isJerry) TheMouse("Jerry") else TheMouse("NotJerry")
  }

  TheMouse(true)
```

---

If you want to add some parameter to constructor, just add it:

```
   class AnimalFactory(clazz: SomeClass){
       def doSomething = clazz.name

       def apply(name: String)
   }

   val dogFactory = new AnimalFactory(dogClassDescriptor)
   val catFactory = new AnimalFactory(catClassDescriptor)

   dogFactory("Spike")
   catFactory("Tom")
```

You can even create a factory for factory (I wouldn't recommend - this solution already looks overcomplicated):

```
   object AnimalFactory{ //please don't use classes for that - avoiding `new` is not their purpose
     def apply(clazz: SomeClass) = new AnimalFactory(clazz)
   }
   val dogFactory = AnimalFactory(dogClassDescriptor)
   //or even `val spike = AnimalFactory(dogClassDescriptor)("Spike")`
```

But still what's the point if you could just provide underlying `clazz` either as a member or just in a wrapper:

```
  final case class ClazzWrapper[T <: Animal](clazz: SomeClass, animal: T)
```